# MongoDB - Query a value in a dictionary

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary

I have a **Conversations** collection, containing **Conversation** documents like so (simplified to get to the point):

```
public class Conversation
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<ObjectId, DateTime> Members { get; set; }
}
```

The Dictionary **Members** is mapping the **Member Ids** to their entry date in the conversation.

Then, in the **Conversations** collection, if, for a particular **User**, I want to query all the **Conversations** he's in, what I'm doing is the following:

```
public List<Conversation> GetConversations(in User user)
{
    Query = Builder.Eq(doc => doc.Members.ContainsKey(user.Id), true);
    return Find(Query).ToList();
}
```

The question being, is this the right way to do it?

- If it is, why? How does MongoDB process this kind of query (which at
  first glance looks to be complex and demanding lot of computing
  power)?
- If it's not how'd you do it better?

Comment: What is the `Builder` class you're using in the example?

Comment: Also, What serialization conventions do you have set up for `Dictionary<,>` as the default dictionary representation of document only allows strings for keys?

Comment: `Builder` is a `FilterDefinitionBuilder<Conversation>` (and `Query` is a `FilterDefinition<Conversation>`). And for the dictionary, yes I was a bit too fast, ids are stored as string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query = Builder.Eq(doc => doc.Members.ContainsKey(user.Id), true);
```

Looks like a collection scan.

Is it possible for you to track conversations in every Member document?
It can be achieved with array or subcollection.

Comment: I was also thinking about it. Issue is, the User document is loaded everytime one is signing in. The more the coversation he's in, the document can grow indefinitely and end up with memory issue... Again I simplified the code, but I'm never asking for every conversations for user, just the latest ones (I should have maybe pointed that out, as the code suggests all the user's conversations are loaded everytime).

Comment: Im not sure but subcollections are not loaded initially with parent document and they don't affect parent document size. Would you use that?

Comment: So you mean creating a sub-collection with just a dated documents mapping one user id to one conversation id? Because a list of conversation id in one document is anyway ending up to the same memory issue I stated above everytime I would load it..

Comment: Yeah, every subcollection document may contain those 2ids with additional information for view like display name of conversation, member name and date.